# Connecting MS Access Database with my project

Tags: java, database, jsp, ms-access-2010

I m trying to execute this code & it shows successfull execution but i cant get any value n access database file which i had create.
so, please find mistake in my code so that i can get some values in database table.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String filename ="D:\\Database for Mini Project\\Database21(example).mdb";
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:\\Database for Mini Project\\Database21(example).mdb";
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","")) {
            Statement s = con.createStatement();
            String b=request.getParameter("uname");

            String c=request.getParameter("pass");
            String query="insert into A.ABC1(uname,pass) values='"+b+"','"+c+"'";

            s.executeQuery(query);
            s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

change `s.executeQuery(query);` to `s.executeUpdate(query);`

For data manipulation language use `executeQuery();` as mentioned in [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String filename ="D:\\Database for Mini Project\\Database21(example).mdb";
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:\\Database for Mini Project\\Database21(example).mdb";
        String b=request.getParameter("uname");
        String c=request.getParameter("pass");
              try {
            // connects to the database
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( database ,"","")) {
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
             String query="insert into A.ABC1(uname,pass) values(?,?);
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            s.setString(1, b);
            s.setString(2, c);

            int row = s.executeUpdate();
            if (row > 0) {
                message = "Query executed";
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) { //catch ur msaccess exception..I use mysql
            message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

I use mysql as my database..so wherever there is catch(SQLException ex) replace it with msaccess exception..

Comment: "thanks @Corleone" but still i cant able insert values in ms-access from your code.

Comment: @user3030268 try now...this should work...plz reply back if it doesnt

Comment: Hey @Corleone, i m new to ms-access database & servlet, so i still wouldn't able to insert any data to database.I m sending u my code pls find mistake

Comment: Sorry sir but When i copy your code there comes a lots of error.

Comment: @Override
    Protected  void doGet(HttpServletRequest request = null , HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException

Comment: error come in this portion of code.
Should i delete this whole portion??

Comment: @user3030268  doPOST and not doGet..just copy paste the error u getting in your question above..i wont understand if u tell me simply like this

Comment: illegal start of type

';' expected

variable request is already defined in method processRequest(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)

variable HttpServletResponse is already defined in method processRequest(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)

';' expected

not a statement

';' expected
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)

Comment: the best thing u do is add ur full code in ur question above...I will do the changes which i can do...

Comment: or else see if this link helps http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/jsp_Ms.Access_datasource.htm

Comment: ok sir,
i will go through this link
& if i found some mistake then i will contact u.
thank u sir for helping me

Comment: i m no sir...I m fresher..just helpin u..i also faced similar problems initially

Comment: @Mohit did the link help?